# Jquery: Give each Div an individual ID

Tags: jquery

I have a set of divs with the same class. I need to give each one an individual ID. And then apply that ID to the href of a link.

Here is the HTMl:

```
<div class="person-promo">
  <a href="***#ID-OF-SIBLING-DIV***" class="action">&gt; Read More</a>
  <div class="hide">
    <div id="***NUMBER-GOES-HERE***" class="person-details">
      <!-- -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- Person Promo -->
```

Each anchor needs to link to its sibling Div, if that makes sense.

I have been hunting around various sites, and the Jquery library for a few hours, but have had no luck. Just hoping for a bit help.

Thanks for everyone's help by the way. It's good to know *SOME* fellow developers will help each other out during difficulties. It is a great community on here.

Comment: Have you tried this? We're not here to do your work for you just help you with your problems ;-)

Comment: That does make sense, but it doesn't make sense to to it in jQuery. You should generate these id's when the output is generated on the server.

Comment: I have been hunting around various sites, and the Jquery library for a few hours, but have had no luck. Just hoping for a bit help.

Comment: Also, giving them those IDs won't make them show up magically. You'll need some code for that too.. :)

Comment: @Guy - btw, I removed an extra `</div>` tag when updating the formatting. It was probably just a copy-paste issue, but I wanted to let you know in case it matters elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
// Loop through the divs
$(".person-promo .person-details").each(function(i) {
    // Store an id with format "uniqueId_{index}" in a variable.
    var id = "uniqueId_" + i;
    // Give the ID to the div
    $(this).attr("id", id);
    // Give it to the sibling link
    $(this).siblings("a").attr("href", "#" + id);
});
```

That said, you should probably generate all this server-side.

Comment: What would I have to do if the link is not a sibling? The .person-details DIV is inside of another DIV. So the <a> is a sibling of that div?

Comment: `$(this).parent().siblings("a")`. JQuery is fun. Here's an excellent compilation of how to traverse the DOM, using it: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Brilliant. It is so simple. Just getting into it.

Answer (score 1):

Using counters seems a bit overkill, since there's an inbuilt index number available anyway...

```
$(".person-promo").each(function(Index) {
    $(this).find("action").attr("href", "#person" +Index);
    $(this).find(".person-details").attr("id", "person" + Index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do:

```
var i = 0;
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$('.person-promo').each(function(){
    var theID = str.charAt(i);
    i++;
    $(this).find('a.action').attr("href", "#"+theID);
    $(this).find('.person-details').attr("id", theID);
});
```

Don't forget, you should never use integers as an ID

Comment: the reason I use alphabet is it's much more easy to reference in the code, using string+int

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = 0;
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href','#anchor' + id);
    $(this).find('div').attr('id','anchor' + id);
    id++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also bind a click event to the `<a>` elements to find the specific div like this

```
$('a.action').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var div_details = $(this).parent().find('.person-details');
  // use div_details to show or hide etc..
})
```